# Merge values of differents csv Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I need to insert a specific value on `Bidfloor`column but my problem is when I run `df_g['Bidfloor'] = df_g[['Sitio', 'Country']].merge(df_seg, how='left').Precio` the `Bidfloor`column takes values as NaN instead of the value of `floorprice` and the I have the same problem with `df_g['Bidfloor'] = df_g[['Sitio', 'Espacio', 'Country']].merge(df_seg, how='left').Precio`

```
floorprice = 0.17
df_g = pd.read_csv('este_mes.csv')
df_g = df_g[df_g.Subastas > 1000]
df_g.to_csv('aaaa.csv')
df_seg = pd.read_csv('output.csv', names=['Espacio', 'Country', 'Precio', 'Sitio'])
df_g['Bidfloor'] = floorprice
df_g['Bidfloor'] = df_g[['Sitio', 'Country']].merge(df_seg, how='left').Precio
df_g['Bidfloor'] = df_g[['Sitio', 'Espacio', 'Country']].merge(df_seg, how='left').Precio
df_g.to_csv('Analizador_{}.csv'.format(auth), index=False)
```

Output:

```
Sitio,Espacio,Tamano,Country,Impresiones_exchange,Importe_a_cobrar,eCPM,Subastas,Fill_rate,Bidfloor
A,3619717 - www.A.com.ar - Seccion - Seccion300x250B,300x250,DE - Germany,846,0.21,0.25,1312,64.48,0.1
B,3619717 - www.A.com.ar - Seccion - Seccion300x250B,300x250,AR - Argentina,846,0.21,0.25,1312,64.48,NaN
```

output I need:

```
Sitio,Espacio,Tamano,Country,Impresiones_exchange,Importe_a_cobrar,eCPM,Subastas,Fill_rate,Bidfloor
A,3619717 - www.A.com.ar - Seccion - Seccion300x250B,300x250,DE - Germany,846,0.21,0.25,1312,64.48,0.1
B,3619717 - www.A.com.ar - Seccion - Seccion300x250B,300x250,AR - Argentina,846,0.21,0.25,1312,64.48,0.2
```

df_g:

```
Sitio,Espacio,Tamano,Country,Impresiones_exchange,Importe_a_cobrar,eCPM,Subastas,Fill_rate
A,3619717 - www.A.com.ar - Seccion - Seccion300x250B,300x250,DE - Germany,846,0.21,0.25,1312,64.48
B,3619717 - www.A.com.ar - Seccion - Seccion300x250B,300x250,AR - Argentina,846,0.21,0.25,1312,64.48
```

df_seg:

```
Espacio,Country,Precio,Sitio
3619717 - www.A.com.ar - Seccion - Seccion300x250B,DE - Germany,0.1,A
*,AR - Argentina,0.2,A
```

Comment: you should provide at least part of the data so that we know what we are dealing with. Also what exactly is the question here?

Comment: Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and edit your question.

Comment: I edited my question. Please, check it @D_Serg

Comment: That's really still not enough for us to answer this. Are your index values the same between the two datasets?

Comment: I edited again @EdwardBrennan

Comment: I edited again @D_Serg

Answer (score 0):

I think your underlying problem here is that you are not being specific enough with your merge statements. As the [Pandas merge documentation says](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html), if you don't put any values for the `on` argument, and also leave the `left_index` and `right_index` arguments `false`, then pandas defaults to merging on the intersection of the columns by default. This means that it only joins rows if the values from **every** common column are the same.

In your example, your merge doesn't return anything for the second row because of the `Sitio` column. In `df_g`, the second row has a value of 'B' for this column, while in `df_seg`, the second row has a value of 'A':

[image: Initial DataFrame Values]

When you run the merge the way you did, you would only return the first row:
[image: Simple Merge]

You need to either remove the `Sitio` column from the DataFrame before merging:
[image: Simple Merge 2]

explicitly specify which columns to merge on:
[image: Explicit List of Columns]

or merge based on some commonly shared index:
[image: Index Merge]

[Here](https://gist.github.com/EdMan1022/5f320997bfe8ebf0299fc240bc15d14f) is a link to the scrap code I used for this (sorry if it looks kind of weird Gists don't seem to handle Jupyter notebooks well).